# Your client issued a request that was too large

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

We are facing problem on static map url when we are passing string of multiple latitude and longitude

We have use static map url to plotting latitude longitude on google map
but it has given url too large error.
we have tried on google map view but it doesn't give the output in image format.

We want a image with plotted latitude and longitude from static map url or map view control.we have 2000 latitude and longitude for plotting at same time.

Comment: Can you please show the error.

Comment: 413. That’s an error.

Your client issued a request that was too large. That’s all we know.

Answer (score 0):

hope to help you~

http://border0902.pixnet.net/blog/post/226423357-google-map-%E5%A4%9A%E5%9C%B0%E6%A8%99google%E5%9C%B0%E5%9C%96

```
var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 5,
    center: latlng, 
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

// add point
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(24.041404,130.446438), 
    title: "test1",
    map: map
});
var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(25.041399,121.452435,
    title: "test2", 
    map: map
});

var marker3 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(25.542591,125.454434),
    title: "test3", 
    map: map
});
```

Comment: I tried this. The problem with the static map url which limit exceeds because of multiple latitude and longitude